# Store not syncing when sync function is overridden Sencha Touch 2.3

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm creating an offline mode for my app and I need to override the sync function on my stores. However, when I do this the store no longer syncs even when I call `this.callParent(arguments)`.

Here is the overridden function:

```
sync: function(){
    if(appOnline){
        console.log('App is online');
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }   
    else{
        console.log('App is offline');
        var found = false;

        for(var i = 0; i < storeSyncList.length; i++){
            if(storeSyncList[i] === this){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!found)
            storeSyncList.push(this);
    }   
}
```

Why is `this.callParent(arguments)` not working? When the app goes online the function is called like this:

```
storeSyncList[i].sync.call(storeSyncList[i],{
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success){
        console.log('test1');
        console.log('successful sync: '(success ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
    }
});
```

As you can see on the call, I'm passing in the store as the `this` portion of `sync.call()`. `storeSyncList[i]` is the current store being synced when the app goes back online.

Does anyone know why the `this.callParent(arguments)` wouldn't be doing the sync when `this` is the store? I know it's not. When I look at the database it isn't updated and the `callback` function is never called. However, I know for sure that it is running the `sync.call` line. What's going on here?

UPDATE: After debugging line by line the call to `this.callParent(arguments)` is being skipped over. I cannot step into the function and it is never run, the program just passes over it as if it's not there and goes to the end of the function. Very odd. Anyone know why?

EDIT: Pastebin of whole class http://pastebin.com/WMZTh5PR
sync is at the bottom.

Comment: Can you showme all the code of your AppStore? Did you added the override option? When I say appStore I mean your main store you want to replace to all other stores.

Comment: @Scoup Not sure what the override option is, but here's the link to the store, the sync function is at the bottom: http://pastebin.com/EqrqgA68

Comment: @Scoup here's the pastebin with syntax highlighting: http://pastebin.com/WMZTh5PR

Answer (score -1):

If you need to override some object, the best way is use the option "override".

```
Ext.define('Airit.store.App', {
    override: 'Ext.data.Store',
    sync: function() {
       this.callParent(arguments)
       //etc
    }
});
```

Just use the "require" for this.

Comment: How is this different from `extend`?

Comment: Looking at the definition of `override` here: http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/classsystem.html Override does not seem to be what I need. I definitely need to create a new class definition in this case.

Comment: Hun... I got it. Use a console.log("this") on your sync to see who is it.

Comment: You can see the object name and see if is what you are expecting.

Comment: I did that before I posted this question. The `this` is referring to the store like it should. I mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: Sorry, but I cant find any problem with your code. You can try to override dataStore.sync and see if is called.